# iphone i1i8n - Added "en" localization, not english in canadian store

Tags: ios, localization, app-store

I have set my app on iTunes connect with fr_CA as my default language (yes I know it was not my best move for scalability).

Now, I added "en" localization to my app, the problem is in the Canadian english App store, it still shows up in french! In the US App store, it's perfectly in english tho...

I thought that by adding "en", it would work for en_CA, en_US, en_GB and so on, no? or does "en" stands for US english?

From the developper doc:

> "the English language as it is spoken in Great Britain would yield a language ID of en-GB, while the English language spoken in the United States would have a language ID of en-US. To specify the generic version of the English language, you would use the language ID en by itself."
>
> "For example, if you did not need to distinguish between different regions of the English language, you could include a single en.lproj directory to support users in the United States, Great Britain, and Australia. "

I18n is working A1 in the app, the only problem is in itunes...

you can try it here:
[Canadian Store](http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/taxes-quebec/id452649179?mt=8) (french - should be in english)
[US Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/taxes-quebec/id452649179?mt=8) (perfect in the US Store)
[Britain Store](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/taxes-quebec/id452649179?mt=8) (french in GB store too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

couldn't you just rename fr_CA to fr and set the developer default language to en? Project -> Target -> Info -> "Localization native development region" = en_US

But the localization in the AppStore have (nearly) nothing to do with the App bundle. You can change the text displayed in iTunes Connect. Go to your app, navigate to localizations and add the localizations for Canada and Great Britain ;)

Here is the documentation:
Adding a New Localization (Page 63):   https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf

(Login to iTunes Connect, Manage Apps, select your App, view Details, Manage Localizations)

Comment: In the App bundle, everything is fine (the app translate well if the phone is in english/french), the only problem is the App Store really :/ But in the App Store, I have to add the language in my App bundle first, so I'll have duplacate fr.lproj anf fr_CA.lproj?

Comment: No you don't need to implement all languages in your app. But you can have all languages in the app store / iTunes. Just as @Allen wrote again, simply add the localization in iTunes Connect

Comment: Ok, so "English" language in iTunes Connect != "Canadian english" if I must do this?

Comment: OK, looks like "English" only is US english, that's why you need to add other types of english I suppose... Thanks for your time, next time I'll make sure to put my default itunes connect language to English!

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Allen here. iTunes descriptions have nothing to do with your App, it's itunes connect stuff.

1. Go to itunesconnect.apple.com
2. Go to Manage Your Applications
3. Choose your App
4. Click on its **Next Version** -> Yes, you will have to create a new version, re-upload a binary and pass Apple's approval to see any changes on your App descriptions.
5. Edit your main metadata description if it is in French it should be in English.
6. Click on Manage Localizations
7. If you have the Canadian English and Canadian French versions already added then edit its descriptions to set them in the correct languages, if not, to add any language go to Add New Language.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

this should be done at iTunes Connect, and it's nothing related to your actual app, when you prepare a new version, you will see a blue button says Manage Localizations, then Add New Language, it will allow you add multiple iTunes Store descriptions for different iTunes Stores.